# Sharepoint server 2013 professional , is showing SharePoint foundation core patches

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, administration, licensing

I have SharePoint server 2013 professional , as shown below:-

[image]

But when I checked the patches inside central administration web aplication, I found that I have many SharePoint foundation patches, as follow:-

[image]

Also when I create a new web application , I will get the following message that “The Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web application has been created.”

[image]

So I am not sure what is doing on, do i have foundation or server license ? can anyone advice ?

Comment: did you install the FOundation CU or Server? One thing keep in mind, SharePoint Server Build on top of SharePoint Foundation that's why many places you will see the SPF...

Comment: now windows update tools refer to foundation & server CUs , so on our staging server i install both CUs for server and foundation. So is there any problem ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to install both CU's for SP Server. Installing the SP Server CU's installs both Foundation and Server updates. As Waqas Sarwar said SP Server is built on top of Foundation

Comment: @z.rahui OK but in my case windows update tools showed 4 CUs. three for them are for SP server, while one of them is for SP foundation. now if i do not install the foundation cU , my farm build number will not be updated to 4667 ... once i install the foundation CU , and i run the configuration wizard, the farm build number was changed to 4667... so this means that i need to install the foundation cU..

Comment: You shouldn't need to. Are you running the Farm Config wizard after the install? Refer to this on the KB for Nov 2014 update -  "This cumulative update package contains all the .msp files that we released as hotfixes or as public updates that target SharePoint Server 2013. This update package also targets SharePoint Foundation 2013. Therefore, you do not have to install those packages separately."